# Command line(@angular/cli) not install in angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have to install npm and node

npm version - 6.4.0

node version -v6.3.1

when I have to install  **npm install -g @angular/cli**   an error occurred in npm

I was trying  **npm install -g npm@latest**   but same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA6oz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For working with `@angular/cli` you need to install *Node JS* higher than **6.9.7**

Comment: I try this: sudo npm install -g update-node
then  version not updated

Comment: You need to remove NodeJs and install again. npm can not update NodeJS

Comment: @PeS I will reinstall node and npm.and if it works I will inform that.

Comment: Hello, Guys, I updated a node and npm version  it's work thanks again @ Suren Srapyan and @PeS